# How to install inotify-tools using microdnf

Tags: linux, docker

I'm working on a docker with `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal` linux system, and it has to use microdnf to install packages. I need to use `inotifywait` to listen to the creation and content of a file, but it only comes with an `inotify` package.

I searched the installation of the `inotify` package but can't find the one that uses microdnf.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable EPEL first:

> rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

Then you should be able to run:

> microdnf install inotify-tools